# Angular2 redirect to custom error page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I've implemented my custom error handler, and in that I want to re-direct to my custom error page that just says "sorry, an error occurred......".

I declared a route under my app-routing.module.ts file like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { NoContentComponent } from './no-content/no-content.component'
import { CustomErrorComponent } from './customerror/customerror.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'resources',  loadChildren: 'app/educational-materials/educational-materials.module#EducationalMaterialsModule' },
    { path: 'administrative',  loadChildren: 'app/dsc/dsc.module#DSCModule' },
    { path: 'ask-a-question',  loadChildren: 'app/aaq/aaq.module#AAQModule' },
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: NoContentComponent },
    { path: 'error', component: CustomErrorComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And in my global exception handler, I've implemented this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class GlobalExceptionErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    private router: Router;

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        setTimeout(() => this.router = injector.get(Router));
    }

    handleError(error) {
        console.log('globalExceptionHandler | handleError...');

        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
    }
}
```

In this file, when I place the forward slash in front of `error`, it re-directs to /error url, but says 404 page missing. (It obviously did NOT go to my CustomErrorComponent page).

If I remove the front slash from the `this.router.navigate(['error'])`, then it does NOTHING.

How do I get this to call my `CustomErrorComponent` I have defined in my app-routing.module.ts file?

Edit:

Here's the CustomErrorComponent:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class CustomErrorComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

And the html for that page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h3>Sorry, an error occurred processing your request. The error has been logged.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit2: Is it possible that the route is not configured in the correct place? I would think the route would need to be defined "at the root", but it acts like it doesn't exist (hence not re-directing).

**Edit3:** When I mentioned in the comments that it was hitting my `handleError` function 20 times, I wasn't spitting out the error...well, I turned that on and look what shows up now (this occurs when my `this.router.navigate(['/error'])` contains the front slash):

> No component factory found for CustomErrorComponent. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents

So next, I added this to my CustomErrorComponent file:

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    entryComponents: [CustomErrorComponent]
})

export class CustomErrorComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('customErrorComponent | ngOnInit...');
    }
}
```

Now I get this just loading the app:

> Component CustomErrorComponent is not part of any NgModule or the
>   module has not been imported into your module

Every place I've tried adding the CustomErrorComponent fails. Where should I be registering my component?

Comment: Can you add all relevant code please?

Comment: Why are you using setTimeout and injector to get the router?

Comment: What happen when you go directly to a page of your app from the navigation bar of the browser?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia there was a cyclic dependency when trying to inject Router via the constructor. This was a "common" problem found when implementing the CustomErrorHandler. SO has lots of questions about it...

Comment: @camaron it navigates to that page....

Comment: @ganders, great, was just to check if there was a problem with the routes of your server. Show us your `app-routing.module.ts` file.

Comment: @camaron updated the routing file to show everything...

Comment: @ganders, move the route `**` to the last position of your `routes` var and check the error page again.

Comment: @camaron doing that made my handleError function get called a total of 20 times, but it still never navigated away from the page that I am [purposely] throwing an error. Edit: next I tried removing the `/` from the `this.router.navigate` line, then it only hit my `handleError` function once, but it didn't navigate OR go to the /error page

Comment: @camaron if you're still watching, check out edit 3 above.

Comment: @ganders I am here, add your `CustomErrorComponent ` to  the `entryComponents: []` of your main NgModule.

Comment: @camaron I put it after `providers: [...]` and before `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` and still get the same error

Comment: @ganders remove the `entryComponents: [CustomErrorComponent]` from your `@Component({})`. Just keep the `entryComponents: [CustomErrorComponent]` inside of your main NgModule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145217/discussion-between-ganders-and-camaron).

Comment: why start bounty on an answered question? what can we do for you?

Comment: @Val I appreciated the time camaran spent helping me so I wanted to reward him/her for it. Just had to wait the default times to get the bounty created and awarded, even though the answer was already marked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main issue is that the `routes` var from the `app-routing.module.ts` has the entry to `**` before the entry to `error` and the router will always go to `**`.

Moving the entry `**` to the last place inside of `routes` will make the `error` entry reachable.

Also we found that after the updates the `@Component({})` decorator of the `CustomErrorComponent` was removed.

Let's rollback that again and leave the `CustomErrorComponent` file with this code:

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "customErrorComponent",
    templateUrl: './customerror.component.html'
})

export class CustomErrorComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('customErrorComponent | ngOnInit...');
    }
}
```

Also we must add the `CustomErrorComponent` to the `entryComponents` of your main module.

Just add `entryComponents: [CustomErrorComponent]` to your main Module.

That did the job, future readers can check the chat thread of the question for more information.