# Navigating to Custom Error Page - Original Page Still Displays

Tags: angular

I am attempting to implement a very simple error handler in my Angular 5 application. Whenever an error occurs, I merely wish it to show a custom error page. I built my custom error handler with reference to [this article](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/global-error-handling-with-angular2-6b992bdfb59c).

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
     super();
    }
    handleError(error) {
      console.log("Custom error handler.");
      const router = this.injector.get(Router);
    router.navigate(["/error"]);
    throw(error);
    }
  }
```

The application does enter the `CustomErrorHandler`. However, it does not fully redirect to the old page. Instead, the error "page" (which just says "error works" for now) appears above the original page that threw the error. The URL in the address bar *does* change from /ticket to /error, but both the error and ticket views/templates are shown.

[image]

I have referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202879/angular2-redirect-to-custom-error-page) and added my ErrorComponent to the entryComponents array.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    LoadingModule.forRoot({
      animationType: ANIMATION_TYPES.circleSwish,
      backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
      backdropBorderRadius: '4px',
      primaryColour: '#ffffff',
      secondaryColour: '#ffffff',
      tertiaryColour: '#ffffff'
    }),
    ReportingModule,
    SharedModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    TicketModule,
    NgxResponsiveStackTableModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],

  providers: [TicketService, ReportService, UserService,
    httpInterceptorProviders, UploadService, {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: CustomErrorHandler
    }],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(router: Router) {

  }
}
```

This did not resolve the issue. The template that I am using to trigger the error (for testing)

```
    <h2>Open Tickets</h2>
<div fxLayout="row">
        <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select #sort (change)="sortTickets(sort.value)" placeholder="Sort By.." >
                        <mat-option value="Property">Property</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="Open">Open Date</mat-option>    
                </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div>
        <ngx-loading [show]="isLoading"></ngx-loading>
        <app-ticket-table *ngIf="!isLoading" [tickets]=tickets></app-ticket-table>
</div>
```

and its corresponding TypeScript.

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-ticket',
  templateUrl: './ticket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ticket.component.scss']
})
export class TicketComponent implements OnInit {

  tickets : TicketModel[];
  isLoading :boolean;

  constructor(private ticketService : TicketService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
  this.ticketService.getUserTickets().subscribe((res)=> {
    this.tickets = res;
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
  }
```

I do have an interceptor that responds to Http errors. I tried temporarily disabling it in case that was causing the issue, but it did not fix the problem.

```
export class LoggingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private authService: AuthService) {    }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
        .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {             
            console.log(err);
            return _throw(err.message);
        });

};
}
```

The routing for my app is simple:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "error", component: ErrorComponent},
{  path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and for the TicketModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: "ticket",

  canActivate: [UserGuard],
  children: [
    { path: "new", component: TicketAddComponent },
    { path: ":id", component: TicketDetailComponent },
    { path: "", component: TicketComponent }

  ]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TicketRoutingModule { }
```

I only have a single router outlet (in my root app component)

```
  <mat-toolbar>    
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                <img src="../assets/logo.png" />
            </a>
            <span class="fill-space"></span>
            <div  fxHide.lt-md=true  *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn" >
                    <a mat-button routerLink="/">Home</a>
                    <a mat-button routerLink="/ticket">View Tickets</a>
                    <a mat-button routerLink="/ticket/new">New Ticket</a>
                    <a mat-button routerLink="/report">Reports</a>           
            </div>
    <div fxHide.gt-sm=true  *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn">
        
                <mat-menu   #appMenu="matMenu">
                        <a mat-button routerLink="/">Home</a>
                        <a mat-button routerLink="/ticket">View Tickets</a>
                        <a mat-button routerLink="/ticket/new">New Ticket</a>
                        <a mat-button routerLink="/report">Reports</a>     
                      </mat-menu>
                      <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
                            <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                          </button>
    </div>

    </mat-toolbar>
<div id="content" class="container  mat-typography ">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are there any error in the console? Are the behaviors of the page broken? If so, it may be because of not handling the error after it is thrown at the end of `handleError` function.

Comment: Based on the console output, it seems to progress as follows: error object is logged (presumably from my HttpInterceptor) -> prints "Custom error handler" -> logs an "Uncaught exception".  If I remove the `throw(error)` statement, it does the same things (less the final Uncaught Exception log). Thanks.