# Angular 2 - Refresh page 404 in production mode without useHash configured

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 2, and I didn't use `useHash`.

I found that the url cannot be visited directly in browser, which would return 404 not found.

I googled a lot and tried following ways:

1. Adding `LocationStrategy` with `PathLocationStrategy`;
2. Changing the `loadChildren` to relative path.

But none worked.

Could anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: You mean like using `router` on some hosting without using `useHash`?

Comment: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` without setting the `useHash` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand it well. You need to solve this in `.htaccess` file. You will probably just need to update it with redirect to `index.html`. Since in Angular everything is in `index.html` after build.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also it is necessary to have all `loadChildren:` defined like this `loadChildren: './path'`. Because the newer syntax `loadChildren: () => ModuleName` cause Runtime compiler error.

Comment: This is not working. Did you get it work on your side?

Comment: Have you used this in your remote server? I start my local with `ng serve`, so I directly deploy it to remote server.

Comment: I have build my code with `ng build --prod` and put content of dist to my remote server. And updated the `.htacess`.

Comment: probably duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202879/angular2-redirect-to-custom-error-page

Comment: @Sky You want to access error page defined like `**`? Or just don't want to use useHash on web?

Comment: @JosefKatič I don’t want to use hash.

Comment: @Sky Do you use `loadChildren: './some.module#SomeModule'`?

Comment: So you have updated `.htacess` file on server and use this kind of `loadChildren:`?