# How can we use custom HTML 404 page in angular

Tags: angular, routes, customization

I am able to create a 404 error page component (HTML, SCSS, TS) and redirect the user to that component if the URL provided is wrong.
But if I want to allow the user to upload a html file and use that HTML file for the 404 error page component what should I have to do in angular?
Or is there any other way available to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 redirect to custom error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202879/angular2-redirect-to-custom-error-page)

Comment: No i am able to redirect to custom page. But i want that page to be customizable by the user. User can upload a html page in some location and that html should be displayed for error page component

Comment: i wouldn't allow the user to upload a complete page. if you provide the ability to add a style sheet, and custom text and then display that. ofc this is without knowing the full context

Comment: Just in case if i wanted to allow the user to upload their own html file and if i want to show that html whenever invalid url is provided what should i have to do?

Comment: personally I would set it up serverside. e.g. with php/nodejs

Comment: Do you have any pointers. I haven't worked on server side :(